# What are the Star Wars scenes parodied in this Hanukkah Star Wars parody?

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, music-identification

Jewish acapella group Six13 released their annual Hanukkah video - a parody of famous Star Wars movies and scenes.

What are the scenes and songs parodied in the video?

(I have yet to watch the third movie in the Original Trilogy (on my to-do list) or the rest of the movies, so I cannot answer this myself.)

Answer (score 4):

The opening including the scrolling text that sets the stage is the classic Main Theme from episode 4, "A New Hope" AKA "Star Wars". The episode is 613.

40 seconds: Imperial March. I don't think this has a direct link to a scene in the movies except that the "jedi" are keeping activities out of sight of Darth Vader.

1:17: Cantina scene on Tatooine, also in "A New Hope". The 2 characters at the table are similar to Han Solo (guy on the right), but does not exactly match the scene.

1:45: This is the music and scene in episode 1, "The Phantom Menace", when Qui Gon and Obiwan Kenobi fight Darth Maul. I think the song is "Duel of the Fates".

2:27: Last song, Throne Room Theme, and scene is from the finale of episode 4, "A New Hope" where Luke Skywalker, Han Solo, and Chewbacca approach Princess Leia and the other leaders of the Rebellion to receive medals. Well, Chewie doesn't get one.